# Fix DataFrame columns when reading an Excel file with a header with merged cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to read with Python Pandas an Excel file which looks like this:

[image: Excel file screenshot]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1usfr3fxfy2qlpp/header_with_merged_cells.xlsx?dl=0

We can see that this Excel file have a header with merged cells

I did

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("header_with_merged_cells.xlsx", skiprows=3)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.columns)
```

it returns a DataFrame like:

```
        ColA ColB ColC  Unnamed: 3           Unnamed: 4 ColD
0        NaT  NaN    1         2.0                    3  NaN
1 2010-01-01    A    A         2.1  2010-02-01 00:00:00    E
2 2010-01-02    B    C         2.2  2010-02-02 00:00:00    F
```

`dtypes` like:

```
ColA          datetime64[ns]
ColB                  object
ColC                  object
Unnamed: 3           float64
Unnamed: 4            object
ColD                  object
```

`columns` like:

```
Index(['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4', 'ColD'], dtype='object')
```

Is there a way to fix columns to get `ColA, ColB, ColC.1, ColC.2, ColC.3, ColD` or MultiIndex columns ?

One issue is that D5 cell is considered as `float` (instead of `int` or `str`)
an other issue is that E column should be considered as `datetime64[ns]`

`header` parameter of `read_excel can help:

```
df = pd.read_excel("header_with_merged_cells.xlsx", skiprows=3, header=[0,1])
```

but we get a DataFrame like:

```
ColA                     ColB ColC                               ColD
           Unnamed: 0_level_1    1    2          3 Unnamed: 4_level_1
2010-01-01                  A    A  2.1 2010-02-01                  E
2010-01-02                  B    C  2.2 2010-02-02                  F
```

`dtypes` like:

```
ColA
ColB  Unnamed: 0_level_1            object
ColC  1                             object
      2                            float64
      3                     datetime64[ns]
ColD  Unnamed: 4_level_1            object
dtype: object
```

`columns` like:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD'], [1, 2, 3, 'Unnamed: 0_level_1', 'Unnamed: 4_level_1']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [3, 0, 1, 2, 4]],
           names=['ColA', None])
```

That's odd to see columns such as `Unnamed: 0_level_1`, `Unnamed: 4_level_1`.
Isn't there a way to fix it?

Comment: Fast solution is `df = pd.read_excel("header_with_merged_cells.xlsx", skiprows=3, header=[0,1])`

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware that header could be a list of row index. But there is still some cleanup to do. `ColA                     ColB ColC                               ColD
           Unnamed: 0_level_1    1    2          3 Unnamed: 4_level_1
2010-01-01                  A    A  2.1 2010-02-01                  E
2010-01-02                  B    C  2.2 2010-02-02                  F`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not easy.

First add parameter `header` for creating `MultiIndex` and then rename `Unnamed` column names to empty strings.

```
df = pd.read_excel("header_with_merged_cells.xlsx", skiprows=3, header=[0,1])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x if not 'Unnamed' in str(x) else '')
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'ColA'})
df.columns.names = (None, None)
print(df)
        ColA ColB ColC                 ColD
                     1    2          3     
0 2010-01-01    A    A  2.1 2010-02-01    E
1 2010-01-02    B    C  2.2 2010-02-02    F
```

Comment: That's odd to see that `Unnamed` appears for `ColB`, `ColC` but not for `ColA`